# How to specify port in four-part SQL Server names?

Tags: sql-server

I find in Microsoft's own SQL Server documentation a very brief explanation of multipart names (server.database.schema.object) -- see [link to Transact-SQL syntax conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). However, I do not find there any information or an example of specifying a port when something other than the default port is used by the targeted SQL Server instance.

I did find elsewhere an example with named instance, like "server\instance".db.schema.table, but what if I know only the port number, not any instance name?

How do I indicate the SQL Server instance's port number in the four-part name server.db.schema.table? Can you please provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: The port has nothing to do with 4 part naming, that's why. If you are using 4 part naming, then the linked server you've created has the server name and port number defined within its properties.

Comment: Multipart names is nothing to do with how you connect to SQL Server. Typically you specify a *port* by prefixing with a colon `:` in the connection

Comment: Also, when connecting to an instance, you would use the instance name or the port: `Host\Instance:port` isn't needed; it's `Host`, `Host\Instance` or `Host:Port`. When you use the instance name, then the SQL Server Browser handles the negotiation of the port number.

Comment: It has been many years and my memory is rusty, but I recall having once installed multiple SQL Server instances on the same machine (ServerName\InstanceA, ServerName\InstanceB, ...) I recall that each instance would allocate a separate port number at startup (I can't recall if this was fixed or not) and one common port was used as a port resolver. Most of this was transparent to the app or SSMS user who just connected to ServerName\InstanceX and it magically worked. Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to the question though since port number is nothing you reference as part of t-sql; port number belongs in the connection string or linked server configuration - never done it but possibly t-sql can use ip:port directly in place of a named instance or server name... not sure on that either.

Comment: @TN you're referring to instance names which get resolved to port numbers at connection time by sending SSRP queries to the SQL Browser service on the target machine. The port numbers can be dynamic, meaning that they can be configured to change after each instance restart, but not so dynamic that they change with each and every connection attempt. Because dynamic ports mess with firewalls and other dependant external resources it's recommended that each instance's port numbers are configured to be static.